# Как добиться похожего результата в Qt5?

Tags: c#, qt, winforms, qt5

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Process p = Process.Start("cmd.exe");
            Thread.Sleep(500); // Allow the process to open it's window
            SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);

        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);    

    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]